# My ESD diodes on some specific lines are dying inconsistently

Tags: pcb-design, button, tvs

I made a PCB with 2 connectors for display connection. On one connector are fast signals (SPI + some more signal for display control (reset, A0,...)) and the second connector has signals for 4x buttons and RGB backlight control. Saving money, I have used the same ESD/TVS diode for all line protection, PESD5V0X1UB,135 ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/916/PESD5V0X1UB-1320432.pdf)). All signals are 3,3V.

Now the diodes on the connector with SPI are always OK. But the diodes on the buttons signal lines are **sometimes** dying. Recently I have ordered several PCBs and on 3 of them is one or more diodes shorted <del>after the very first power up(PCB not yet build inside the unit, just lying on ESD-safe table in room without EMI disturbances).</del>    *Edit: I am not sure if the power up is killing them. I should have said "the buttons signal lines are not working on a completely new PCB". The power up may killed them, the first button press or they were damaged before (that would be a lot of bad luck).*

*On the other hand there are also PCB running for 1+ year without any problems with the same configuration (which puzzles me). The PCB batch (10 PCB) I ordered a year ago had 1 PCB with this issue (I assumed I touched it and killed with it static discharge).*

The buttons are switching the signal to GND. The connection and PCB layout (4-layer) is shown below. The only difference between the button line signals and the other signals line are the capacitors and pull-ups. Are they causing the issue? I find it very hard to debug as the issue is not always present + it is really hard to replace the 0402 diode placed so close to the connector. Am I using the diodes wrong?

I used oscilloscope, trying to find if there are any transients on power up or on a button press. I have not found any overshoots/undershoots or disturbance coming from the RGB control. The signal lines are always between -0V and ~3,6V and nice and smooth.

[image: schematic]
[image: PCB layout]

**Edit 1:**
Screenshot from the diode datasheet:

[image]

**Edit 2:**
Adding power distribution network (project names censored). On the connected PCB with the display there is R-78E9.0-0.5 [datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/468/R_78E_0_5-1711129.pdf) generating 9V for the display.

[image]

Comment: This is hard to tell without knowing more details (e.g. power sequence). ESD Diodes don't die from ESD during handling, but they can die easily when they see current over a longer time. Just gut feeling/curiosity, what's the reason for that huge 100 nF cap ??

Comment: Cap is for button debouncing [EMBED WITH ELLIOT: DEBOUNCE YOUR NOISY BUTTONS, PART I](https://hackaday.com/2015/12/09/embed-with-elliot-debounce-your-noisy-buttons-part-i/). What do you mean with "power sequence"?

Comment: you mentioned that these diodes die during power up. So maybe they experience some forward voltage due to the sequence in which power rails and grounds are energized. for this its important to know the power distribution network.

Comment: I have added the power distribution network. The PCB stack is signal-gnd-3,3V-signal

Comment: Do you have anything between PGND and GND ? at least some kind of cap ? With these completely floating designs I don't have much experience. On one hand they can float at 100s of Volts but on the other hand, they nevertheless shouldn't see a lot of earth current.

Comment: There is nothing between PGND and GND. I assumed they are completely separated. In my origin post I said "...shorted after the very first power up" which may not be true. It also could be that the diodes were dead before first power up (assembly problems?) or they were destroyed with fist button press. I will edit the post.

Comment: The buttons definitely switch to GND and not PGND? And why use a 24V supply on your board?

Comment: Definitely to GND. There is no measurable connection between GND and PGND, the Traco datasheet promises isolation up to 1600V.

Comment: Do any of the diodes fail after the board has been in use for a while? From your description they're either faulty on arrival or they work for over a year. Hard to see anything in your circuit that could be causing this. Can the button connector be inserted wrong and apply power across the diodes?

Comment: There is no case of the diode failing after a while. The connector is polarized 10-pole flat cable connector, impossible to fit backwards. I was also thinking about the diodes being faulty on arrival but there is total 12 pieces of PESD5V0X1UB,135 diodes on the board and only the "buttons" ones are going bad... I may just remove them as they do not add any reliabity to the circuit, actually only making it worse.

Comment: I guess removing them is fine, ESD protection is plenty due to debounce circuit and internal ESD protection. Asking the assembly house about an opinion would be a thing, too.